# libgdx: html.nocache.js missing after successfully building war

Tags: java, libgdx, gradlew

I have developed a libgdx game which runs fine under desktop and android.

Unfortunately I can't get the html-output to work. When I start the task `./gradlew war` it takes some time and much CPU power resulting in `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`.

Running `./gradlew jettyRun` gives me a webpage, where the browser tells me: `404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/html/html/html.nocache.js`.
Looking in the war-folder of the html project, the subfolder "html" is missing.

I seems like the files are not copied from `build/gwt/out/html`, where I could locate a `html.nocache.js`. Manually copying the files to the war folder, lets the game start, but with errors, concerning missing classes of my core-project.

What am I doing wrong? I already have tried to use the current libgdx-setup.jar with a new (plain) project, giving me the same results. Even large amounts of googling didn't help.

Comment: use "gradlew html:dist" command to generate deployment files
if you just want to run on debug mode, use "gradlew html:superDev"

Comment: I already tested this, with `gradlew html:dist` the files are also missing

Comment: ok, did you check "\html\build\dist" directory in your project, this directory will be created after you finish executing "gradlew html:dist" command

Comment: I could check it today and you are right, `html:dist` creates the dist-folder containing all files. The Javascript errors are still there - I think that may be another problem for me to solve. But I still wonder why the other commands do not work as expected...

Comment: I'm actually not familiar with other commands, I went through libgdx site wiki and I learnt this 2 commands:

1 --> "gradlew html:superDev" for debugging, once its done with some processing, it will show 1 link where you can setup superdev mode and to access game, goto: http://localhost:8080/html

2 --> "gradlew html:dist" for deployment, it creates all required files, so I copy files from dist folder to desired directory in Jdeveloper to deploy war
FYI: remove "WEB-INF" directory from dist folder, it has nothing to do with game in prod

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My issue was, that I was building the libgdx in different folder from where my gradle project was. The Libgdx build system is probably not ready for that. Double check, that you are using the libgdx default template and you are not using buildDir gradle property